# Parse a long delimited string into new columns in SQL or SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

Im trying to parse out a long string that contains both new column names and values.

| ID | RawData |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {ChangeNotes : "Change", DateValid : "02/26/2021", sys.HeaderID : "WQH010166_1"...} |
| 2 | {ChangeNotes : "Update", DateValid : "02/28/2021", sys.HeaderID : "WQH010170_1"...} |
| 3 | etc... |

Where in quotes are the values and whats before the ":" are the column names. So...

| ChangeNotes | DateValid | Sys.HeaderID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Change | 02/26/2021 | WQH010166_1 |
| Update | 02/28/2021 | WQH010170_1 |

And so on...

Comment: It looks like you have json data, what version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: if this is a JSON data, sql-server have JSON related function (start with sql-server 2016), if this is just a long string or your DBMS not support JSON, you can still do this with `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` in sql-server. assuming those data have same format.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Integration Services does not support JSON natively, so you need to develop a custom source for a data flow task to load JSON file.

You can try this query in SQL Server :

```
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(4000) = 
        '
           [{
       "Id":1,
       "ChangeNotes":"Change",
       "DateValid":"02/26/2021",
       "sys.HeaderID": "WQH010166_1"
               }
               ,
      {"Id":2,
       "ChangeNotes":"Update",
       "DateValid":"02/28/2021",
       "sys.HeaderID": "WQH010170_1"
               }
       
    ]'
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@data,'$') MyData_String
```

As a source of your SSIS package :

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'YourPathToJSONFile', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j



 SELECT * FROM OpenJson(@json)
WITH (Id Int '$.Id',
ChangeNotes VARCHAR(100) '$.ChangeNotes',
DateValid Date '$.DateValid',
sysHeaderID VARCHAR(100) '$."sys.HeaderID"'
)
```

This is a well explained [tutoriel](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5307/importing-json-files-using-sql-server-integration-services/) that helps you develop a custom source for a data flow task to load JSON file.

You will dicover a method to develop a bespoke source to load JSON files using .Net libraries.